# Programmatically Insert Text at active window that is not owned by App

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to code an application, that pastes for example the `DateTime` by just pressing a single button into my active window.

For example:

- My application is running in the backround (Maybe systemtray)
- I am using Google Chrome and want to find out whats happening around the world
- I type "News" into google and press `F7` (or any other programmed key)
- My application detects `F7` was pressed and pastes `Now.ToShortDateString` to the active `Cursor Position` of Google Chrome

Is that possible? I have already figuered out how to grab KeyPresses without my form beeing active by using the Windows Api of `user32.dll`

I also want to avoid using the `clipboard`.
Otherwise i could for example use

```
Dim clipb As String= My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(Now.ToShortDateString)
'simulate CTRL+V
My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(clipb)
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Since it seems that i have to simulate each KeyStroke on my own I decided to switch technique:

- Save clipboard
- Overwrite clipboard
- Simulate CTRL+V
- restore user-clipboard

I managed to write the following code for that:

```
        Dim UserClipboard As Object = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetDataObject()
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(Now.ToString)
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^(v)")
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetDataObject(UserClipboard)
```

It seems to be working for copied Files. 
If I used `My.Computer.GetText()` and `My.Computer.SetText(UserText)` instead it would work for Text. I can't figure out how to tell my application when it should use which function.

Also seems, that simulating `CTRL+V` doesnt work in `WinWord`
Solution for this one: I was using CTRL+SHIFT+U for simulating keysends which is used by winword itself for underlining text.

Comment: Use the Win32 SendMessage function.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible; for example, you could use the windows API to enumerate all windows, find your target window, and emulate keystrokes for it.

I can't tell you how to do that from Visual Basic; I only did it from Visual C++ like 10 years ago.

You might want to have a look at *Keypass*, an open source password safe tool that inserts your username and password that way. You could look at its source code how it does it.